# Cannot find specific SDK function for Fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I want to create a dashboard for identity management using Hyperledger Fabric. I know how to use `fabric-client` and `fabric-network` to call the `FabricCAServices` object and register and enroll new users. However I am unable to access other functions for retrieving list of certificates issued.

The `fabric-ca-client` npm repo does not expose functions that can be called via the CLI as shown here - https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/clientcli.html The `fabric-ca-client certificate xxx` set of commands is what I am looking for.

[This link](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/FabricCAClient.html#newCertificateService__anchor) shows how to get `CertificateService` which seems to have some of the code for certificate queries but there is no further documentation on how to use it. For reference [these files](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/tree/release-1.4/fabric-ca-client/lib) seem to have the functions that I need.

Answer (score 2):

You actually want to use the ***IdentityService***.

```
let opts = {...}; //fill in connect options
let idService = new FabricCAClient(opts).newIdentityService();
let admin = new User(...); //admin user
await user.setEnrollment(...); //fill in parameters
resp = idService.getAll(admin); //list all identities accessible by admin
```